# Can I delete log files if it is still written?

Tags: linux

Suppose I have a log file /opt/mydata.log. Can I delete it if the app is writing on it? Suppose I succeed in deleting it, is it still possible to read the deleted logs since the process is still running? Also, if the process is alive but the log files are deleted is OS able to reclaim the space logs were using?

Answer (score 1):

If you delete it while it is written depending on the writing method, it will be either recreated with new data or space will continue to be written but the file won't be accessible. Third case, the file is written/closed on each new data block so then you will get "file not found" or other type of errors.

On both first cases, you can work around to read the logs dynamically (new data only).

On both first cases, OS cannot claim the disk space until process ends, stops or is killed. (exceptions depending on how the software that write the logs is coded)...